# Endomondo API using oAuth

Tags: php, api, oauth

I'm building a web app which I would like to connect to Endomondo to retrieve the workouts.

I've seen some web applications doing this using what seems to be oAuth, however, I don't seem to be able to find the API documentation in the Endomondo site, what's more, the PHP libraries I've found on Github seem to require the Endomondo username and password, which doesn't seem to be the best option.

Does anyone know where can I get the documentation or at least some information about this API? I'm interested in the oAuth option if there's one, as I'd rather not ask for the username and password.

Comment: Did you manage to get the cliend id and secret from them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no opened official API or documentation from Endomondo team, and I didn't find any Oauth php lib.

But perhaps you can try get the Oauth info from this python lib to sync activities -> https://github.com/cpfair/tapiriik/blob/master/tapiriik/services/Endomondo/endomondo.py

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, this confirms they have a private API. I guess I'll have to contact them and request a client id and secret.

Comment: @Fakito did you find the private API, and procedure on how to apply for it?